# How to make windows bootable auto run usb

Tags: windows, usb, bootable-media, installer

Im trying to make a bootable windows **10** usb that runs a program on startup with no login, i tried modifying the windows bootable install usb however, it did not work. i have also tried making a bootable installation of windows autorun a file but it was too big to put on a usb stick.

Comment: You should look into Windows PE properly instead of trying to hack away at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy to make a bootable USB. All you need to follow these steps:

1. Go to start and type "cmd" and entre.
2. Type "Disk part" in the command prompt and entre.
3. New command prompt would open, type "list disk" and entre
4. Then type "select disk 1" entre
5. Type "clean" and entre.
6. Type "create partition primary" and hit enter.
7. Type 'select partition 1' a hit Enter.
8. Type 'active' and hit Enter.
9. Type 'format fs=ntfs quick' and hit Enter.
10. Type exit.
11. Copy all the window 10 data in pen drive and boot.

Comment: [1] Would this also work on Windows 7?  [2] That seems not to be what he's asking, he's asking how to make a bootable USB which will launch a particulur program at **startup**. You're answering a different question. [3] at step 4 you would have to be sure that **disk 1** is indeed the USB stick and not some other partition or portable HDD

Comment: to clarify: he's not asking how to make a bootable USB, he already seems to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a bootable it is fairly easy for it to run a program on boot.
Try to create a task in the **Task Scheduler**. You can create a task and configure it to run a certain program every time you boot.
Also, you can configure Windows to always login the first time you boot without needing a password. You can use **netplwiz** as describe in this [link](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/automatically-log-in-to-your-windows-10-pc/).

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to do this. If you copy a shortcut to your application in the following windows directory, your application will run immediately on startup without any extra steps.

C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: It is better not to use **C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup** and to use  **%APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup** instead, because the last one is more universal. It would pick the current logged in User anyway. Only if you wanted to do that for _other_ users there would be trouble.